# SQL query to select multiple products in same invoice

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a sql query to show all the invoices. Invoice have multiple products. I used INNER JOIN to select from multiple tables. The result I am getting is:

```
INV No.   Client        Product       Total
---------------------------------------------
inv1   client name1     product1     100.00
inv1   client name1     product2     100.00
inv1   client name1     product3     100.00
inv2   client name2     product1     150.00
inv2   client name2     product3     150.00
```

Is it possible to show result like this:

```
INV No.   Client        Product       Total
---------------------------------------------
inv1   client name1     product1     100.00
                        product2     
                        product3     
inv2   client name2     product1     150.00
                        product3
```

I am using this query for reporting purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.  Such aesthetic work should usually be done in the application layer.  The issue is that the results depend on ordering -- and SQL tables and result sets are generally unordered.

But, you can do it using window functions:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by inv_no order by product) = 1
             then inv_no
        end) as inv_no,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by inv_no order by product) = 1
             then client
        end) as client,
       product,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by inv_no order by product) = 1
             then total
        end) as total
from t
order by inv_no, product;
```

Notice that the outermost query has an `order by` that exactly matches the `partition by` and `order by` clauses for `row_number()`.

Comment: Great! Working.. Thanks you so much..  It is showing NULL in that cells, can we show it blank (" ") ?

Comment: @User27 . . . You can add `else ''` to the string columns.  If some are numbers, then you will need to format the number as a string (say using `str()`) and then use `else ''`.